# Convert time strings to integers

Tags: python, string

I am reading in a file that has a column of times that is in the format of hour, minute, seconds (023456).  There are other columns in the file that I am not dealing with at the time. I have ignored the other values.

```
020746   10   -1
020823    5   -1
020839    6   -1
020812    6    0
```

My goal is to read the column in as a string, then split the time into the corresponding hour, minute, and second as an integer. So far I have this:

```
f = open(file, 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    time = columns[0]
f.close()

hour = int(time[0:2])
minute = int(time[2:4])
second = int(time[4:6])
```

If I put a print statement in the for loop, it prints all of the corresponding times in a string.  However, when I print hour, minute, or second, it only prints out the values of the final time in the time column. For example it will print

```
print(hour)
2
print(minute)
8
print(second)
12
```

Is there a way to print out all of the corresponding hour, minute, and seconds into a list to get:

```
print(hour)
[2, 2, 2, 2]
print(minute)
[7, 8, 8, 8]
print(second)
[46, 23, 39, 12]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, create the second, min, and hour list before your loop, and then append the results of i to each list within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new lists for storing the values and then printing them. Here is what I have done.

```
hourlist,minutelist,secondlist=[],[],[]

f = open("newtext.txt", 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    time = columns[0]
    hourlist.append(int(time[0:2]))
    minutelist.append(int(time[2:4]))
    secondlist.append(int(time[4:6])) 
f.close()

hour = int(time[0:2])
minute = int(time[2:4])
second = int(time[4:6])

print hourlist, minutelist,secondlist
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by pyNoob. Create a `list` with the times and `append` the info to it.

```
time_list = []
f = open(file, 'r')
for line in flash:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    time = columns[0]
    hour = int(time[0:2])
    minute = int(time[2:4])
    second = int(time[4:6])
    time_list.append(hour, minute, second)
f.close()
```